# Solution to a joke related to EBNF

Tags: context-free-grammar, ebnf, context-free-language

What do you think, what is the solution to the following problem related to EBNF?

The following message was seen on a bumper sticker: Stinks Syntax. What is the
joke?

So far this I got to my mind:

```
r1 ::= in | yn
r2 ::= ks | x
Stinks Syntax ::= St r1 r2 | S r1 ta r2

Stynx Sintaks
```

Comment: The joke is that in English, the subject (syntax) must come before the verb (stinks). So that is a syntax error, which the bumper sticker's author is complaining about.

Comment: So I guess this  would be the answer. Should I write an answer or you are going to answer ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joke is that in English, the subject (syntax) must come before the verb (stinks). So that is a syntax error, which the bumper sticker's author is complaining about.